# jQuery tabs with 2 levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, tabs

I'm trying to use Jquery tabs for navigation inside a page.
it works fine.
but I would like to add inside each tab-content, a sub tab content.
like this

1st Tabs nav li :

Content 1 - Content 2 - Content 3 - Content 4

2nd tabs nav (inside Content 1 for example)

Sub Content 1 part 1 - Sub Content 1 part 2 - Sub Content 1 part 3

I'm using this JS which works perfectly for my first level tabs :

```
$('#tab-content div').hide();
$('#tab-content div:first').show();

$('#nav li').click(function() {
    $('#nav li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).find('a').addClass("active");
    $('#tab-content div').hide();

    var indexer = $(this).index(); //gets the current index of (this) which is #nav li
    $('#tab-content div:eq(' + indexer + ')').fadeIn(0); //uses whatever index the link has to open the corresponding box 
});
```

when adding a sub level, with JScript and Css, nothing works anymore...

here is a jsfiddle explaining what I'm trying to achieve... 
http://jsfiddle.net/R85tE/224/
I can't find the problem in my code...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is, you've got this line of code in your JS:

```
$('#tab-content div').hide();
```

But you'd got multiple **children divs** and **grandchildren divs**. So that line above basically hides all the children, including `#tab-content_2` on page load, since it's a grandchild. So your code was working, to an extend, but you couldn't see it working because `#tab-content_2` was hidden.

To solve this, you need to target the direct children:

```
$('#tab-content > div').hide();
```

You'll basically have to add the **greater-than** sign, `>`, wherever you're targeting **divs** in your JS. Something like:

```
$('#x > div').hide() or .show();
```

You can view the solution here but I recommend you read my comment below and hopefully improve on the JS at hand

http://jsfiddle.net/hwQ76/

This solution will solve the problem at hand but I'd recommend you add some classes to the direct children divs, `tab-content`, and to the grandchildren divs, `sub-tab-content`, so you can easily target each group. In addition, you can further shrink down you code into a function so you can reuse it over and over again.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help @EmileKumfa
I use to use pure css tabs navigation before... but I had troubles with the position: absolute... my wrapper did not extend depending of the content height... that's why I wanted to change... i'm not familiar with JS...
One more question, Is it possible to change color of my active tab and children tab ? I managed to do it with css tabs (using :checked) but can't find how to do it with JS...

Comment: Well you've already got the setup, you're already adding an `active` class to the active tabs so you just need to add colors to the active classes in css and it'll work. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BQ2A6/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the selection of the div on clicking the li element.

Instead we should use the jQuery child selector for the required selection of expected div element.

One more problem with Content1 Submenus is their parent is hidden by your code.
I am showing them using the below code

`$('#tab-content_2 > div:eq(' + indexer + ')').parent().show().end().fadeIn(0);`

After the hidden parent is made visible, I am applying your fadeIn method to show the actual div element.

**For more info on jQuery child Selector: ** http://api.jquery.com/child-selector

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/R85tE/227/

Comment: I have changed only the JS, I have added only two lines in each of the methods. Please accept the answer if solved your requirement.

Comment: I've found the changes, thanks ! One more things, is it possible that when on CONTENT 1 tab, the SUB CONTENT 1 PART 1 is displayed without having to click on SUB CONTENT 1 PART 1 tab ? like on the 1st level

Comment: you have explicity hidden the parent, you can use $('#tab-content_2').show(); for showing the parent.